# Docker + nodejs - JavaScript heap out of memory

Tags: node.js, docker

I have a .NET Core & SSR React app and everything runs fine on my computer and on Azure Pipelines and Azure Win and Linux WebApps but when I try to build a Docker Image I always receive 'JavaScript heap out of memory'.

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.0-alpine AS build

RUN apk add --no-cache bash git openssh nodejs npm

RUN git clone -b dev https://github.com/RicardoGaefke/profile4d.git ./app

WORKDIR /app/src/Web.Identity

RUN NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=32768‬

RUN npm install

RUN npm run lint-fix

RUN npm run production1

RUN dotnet publish -c Release ./Web.Identity.csproj -r linux-musl-x64 -o ./publish

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/runtime-deps:3.0-alpine as runtime

EXPOSE 80

WORKDIR /app

COPY --from=build /app/src/Web.Identity/publish ./

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Web.Identity.dll"]
```

And this is my build command:

```
docker build -f ./Dockerfile.web.identity.cloud -t web_identity_cloud .
```

Can anybody please help me?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I am also facing same issue in docker, did you found any solution?

Comment: I replaced npm command with:
```
"production": "cross-env NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=65536 webpack --config webpack.prod.js"
```
It worked for prod build but not for testing code as we have a long test execution.